# Stripe Payment Context Not Connecting to Backend API with Swift 3 & Nodejs

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, xcode, stripe-payments

I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3, NodeJS and Atom

Following Stripe's `Standard iOS Integration Guide` https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard I am getting a simple localized error when calling `paymentContextDidChange`.

This method is called when the user is ready to select a payment, which in turn allows me to call Stripe's prebuilt UI `STPPaymentMethodsViewController`. But I cannot call the function. Instead I am calling the method `didFailToLoadWithError` which typically occurs when there is a network connection error, OR there is an issue connecting to my backend.

Here is my client-side code in Xcode:

```
// MARK: - STPPaymentContextDelegate
func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
    if let paymentMethod = paymentContext.selectedPaymentMethod {
        self.paymentRow.detail = paymentMethod.label
    }
    else {
        self.paymentRow.detail = "Select Payment"
    }
    self.totalRow.detail = self.numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(self.paymentContext.paymentAmount)/100))!
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    MyAPIClient.sharedClient.completeCharge(paymentResult, amount: paymentContext.paymentAmount, completion: completion)
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
    let title: String
    let message: String
    switch status {
    case .error:
        title = "Error ⚠️"
        message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "☹️"
    case .success:
        title = "Success "
        message = "You Have Successfully Made a Charge "
    case .userCancellation:
        return
    }
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Heard", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "Error ⚠️",
        message: error.localizedDescription,
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    })
    let retry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.paymentContext.retryLoading()
    })
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    alertController.addAction(retry)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's my API-Adapter in XCode

```
class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPBackendAPIAdapter {

static let sharedClient = MyAPIClient()
let session: URLSession
var baseURLString: String? = nil
var defaultSource: STPCard? = nil
var sources: [STPCard] = []

override init() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    super.init()
}

func decodeResponse(_ response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> NSError? {
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        , httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
        return error ?? NSError.networkingError(httpResponse.statusCode)
    }
    return error
}


func retrieveCustomer(_ completion: @escaping STPCustomerCompletionBlock) {
    let userInfo = "Could Not Retrieve Stripe Customer"
    guard let key = Stripe.defaultPublishableKey(), !key.contains("#")
        else {
        let error = NSError(domain: StripeDomain, code: 50, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "\(userInfo)"])
        completion(nil, error)
            print("\(userInfo)")
        return
    }
    guard let baseURLString = baseURLString, let baseURL = URL(string: baseURLString)
        else {return}

    let path = "/customer"
    let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)

    let request = URLRequest.request(url, method: .GET, params: [:])
    let task = self.session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let deserializer = STPCustomerDeserializer(data: data, urlResponse: urlResponse, error: error)
            if let error = deserializer.error {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            } else if let customer = deserializer.customer {
                completion(customer, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


func attachSource(toCustomer source: STPSource, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    guard let baseURLString = baseURLString, let baseURL = URL(string: baseURLString)
        else {
        if let token = source as? STPToken, let card = token.card {
            self.sources.append(card)
            self.defaultSource = card
        }
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    let path = "/customer/sources"
    let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
    let params = ["source": source.stripeID]

    let request = URLRequest.request(url, method: .POST, params: params as [String : AnyObject])
    let task = self.session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = self.decodeResponse(urlResponse, error: error as NSError?) {
                completion(error)
                return
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


func selectDefaultCustomerSource(_ source: STPSource, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    guard let baseURLString = baseURLString, let baseURL = URL(string: baseURLString)
        else {
        if let token = source as? STPToken {
            self.defaultSource = token.card
        }
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    let path = "/customer/default_source"
    let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
    let params = ["source": source.stripeID]

    let request = URLRequest.request(url, method: .POST, params: params as [String : AnyObject])
    let task = self.session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = self.decodeResponse(urlResponse, error: error as NSError?) {
                completion(error)
                return
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

// MARK: - Complete Charge
func completeCharge(_ result: STPPaymentResult, amount: Int, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    let userInfo = "Could Not Complete Stripe Customer Charge"
    guard let baseURLString = baseURLString, let baseURL = URL(string: baseURLString)
        else {
        let error = NSError(domain: StripeDomain, code: 50, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "\(userInfo)"])
        completion(error)
        return
    }
    let path = "charge"
    let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
    let params: [String: Any] = ["source": result.source.stripeID as Any, "amount": amount as Any]

    let request = URLRequest.request(url, method: .POST, params: params as [String : AnyObject])
    let task = self.session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = self.decodeResponse(urlResponse, error: error as NSError?) {
            completion(error)
            return
        }
        completion(nil)
    }
}
task.resume()
}

}
```

Here is my backend code in NodeJS

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_....');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Request Token API
const token = request.body.stripeToken;

// Retrieve Customer API
app.get('/customer', function(request, response) {

  var customerId = 'cus_...';
  stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId, function(err, customer) {
    if (err) {
      response.status(402).send('Error retrieving customer.');
      console.log('Could not retrieve customer');
    } else {
      response.json(customer);
      console.log('Success retrieving customer');
    }
  })
});

// Attach a new payment source API
app.post('/customer/sources', function(request, response) {

  var customerId = 'cus_...';
  stripe.customers.createSource(customerId, {
    source: request.body.source
  }, function(err, source) {
    if (err) {
      response.status(402).send('Error attaching source.');
      console.log('Could not attach new payment source');
    } else {
      response.status(200).end();
  console.log('Success attaching new payment source');
    }
  });
});

// Select a new default payment source API
app.post('/customer/default_source', function(request, response) {

  var customerId = 'cus_...';
  stripe.customers.update(customerId, {
    default_source: request.body.defaultSource
  }, function(err, customer) {
    if (err) {
      response.status(402).send('Error setting default source.');
      console.log('Could not select default payment source');
    } else {
      response.status(200).end();
      console.log('Success selecting default payment source');
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: The error is, it calls `didFailToLoadWithError`. The reasons why it could call this function were stated: either no network connection (which I have) or my front-end fails to connect with my backend.

Comment: This method is part of Stripe's STPPaymentContext, one of four necessary to implement to work with payments. The other is an API Adapter class that talks to my backend. My backend is the NodeJS stuff.

Comment: Yes, but which error?

Comment: The `error.localizedDescription` is the only error: **There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds** When I `Retry` it returns the same error. `Cancel` dismisses the VC.

Comment: I am getting same error. Is there any solution for this..?